# angular js modal popup call factory function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to call factory function in my modal popup but it gives error

Here is my factory

```
 .factory('PartnerFactory', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
             var currentPartner;
             var partners = [];
             var currentClient;
             var currentSite
             return {

             savePartner: function (partnerData) {
                 console.log("In Save Partner");
                 console.log(partnerData);

                 var url = "/api/Partner/CreatePartner";

                 var dataToPost = { Name: partnerData.Name, Description: partnerData.Description, Address1: partnerData.Address1 }
                 ////$("#spinner").show();

                 $http.post(url, dataToPost)
                 .success(function (data) {


                 })
                  .error(function (data) {

                      // return $scope.showInfoOnSubmit = !0, $scope.revert()
                  })


             },

             getPartners: function () {
                 var url = "/api/Partner/GetAllPartners";
                 return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                     partners = response.data;
                     $rootScope.$broadcast('handleSharedPartners', partners);
                     return partners;
                 })
             }


         };
     }])
```

Modal dialog

```
 .controller("PartnerModalCtrl", ["$scope","$http", "$modalInstance", "items", '$routeParams','PartnerFactory', function ($scope, $http, $modalInstance,$routeParams, PartnerFactory) {

            $scope.test = function (partnerData) {
                console.log("Test");
                console.log(partnerData);

                return this.PartnerFactory.currentPartner();
            },
             $scope.ok = function () { $modalInstance.close(); },
          $scope.cancel = function () { $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel") },
            $scope.addPartner = function (partnerData) {

                console.log(partnerData);

           return   PartnerFactory.savePartner(partnerData);
            };




        }])
```

I get error as addPartner is not a defined function

Comment: You have commas instead of semicolons in your controller.

And also, in your controller, you seem to inject something called "items", in your "minification-safe part", but that is not passed to the controller-function.

And why use `this`, when calling the PartnerFactory in your controller?
Try these fixes to see if your code works

Answer (score 0):

You have problems in both factory and controller, Have rectified and pasted the code below:

Factory:

```
         savePartner: function (partnerData) {
             console.log("In Save Partner");
             console.log(partnerData);

             var url = "/api/Partner/CreatePartner";

             var dataToPost = { Name: partnerData.Name, Description: partnerData.Description, Address1: partnerData.Address1 }
             ////$("#spinner").show();

             $http.post(url, dataToPost)
             .success(function (data) {
                   //need to return the data from the function 
                   return data;
             })
              .error(function (data) {

                  // return $scope.showInfoOnSubmit = !0, $scope.revert()
              })


         },

         getPartners: function () {
             var url = "/api/Partner/GetAllPartners";
             return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                 partners = response.data;
                 $rootScope.$broadcast('handleSharedPartners', partners);
                 return partners;
             })
         }


     };
 }])
```

Controller:

```
 .controller("PartnerModalCtrl", ["$scope","$http", "$modalInstance", "items", '$routeParams','PartnerFactory', function ($scope, $http, $modalInstance,items,$routeParams, PartnerFactory) {

        $scope.test = function (partnerData) {
            console.log("Test");
            console.log(partnerData);

            return this.PartnerFactory.currentPartner();
        },
         $scope.ok = function () { $modalInstance.close(); }

      $scope.cancel = function () { $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel") }

        $scope.addPartner = function (partnerData) {
            console.log(partnerData);
            return   PartnerFactory.savePartner(partnerData);
        };
    }])
```

If problem persists do create a fiddle so that we can look at the complete code

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply but it still did not solve my problem. Can you please have a look at this fiddle. It does not work http://jsfiddle.net/akhileshgandhi/E7xEb/